# email claim not coming from federated OIDC ADB2C IDP

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

We are using B2C and have successfully connected an AD federation using OIDC, that all works fine.  However, we want to enable an external B2C IdP instance to enable another federation.  We configured our host B2C the same as the AD one, getting the email, firstname, surname from the federation source.

Heres the technical profile to enable federation in our base.xml file

```
<ClaimsProvider>
  <Domain>testdomain</Domain>
  <DisplayName>Login using External Tenant</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="TestDomain">
      <DisplayName>Test domain</DisplayName>
      <Description>Login with your test domain account</Description>
      <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect"/>
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="METADATA">Link to the federated tenant well known endpoint</Item>
        <Item Key="client_id">xxx</Item>
        <Item Key="response_types">code</Item>
        <Item Key="scope">openid email profile</Item>
        <Item Key="response_mode">form_post</Item>
        <Item Key="HttpBinding">POST</Item>
        <Item Key="UsePolicyInRedirectUri">false</Item>
        <Item Key="ClaimTypeOnWhichToEnable">identityProviders</Item>
        <Item Key="ClaimValueOnWhichToEnable">testdomain</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <CryptographicKeys>
        <Key Id="client_secret" StorageReferenceId="testdomain"/>
      </CryptographicKeys>
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" PartnerClaimType="login_hint" />
      </InputClaims>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="issuerUserId" PartnerClaimType="sub"/>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tenantId" PartnerClaimType="tid"/>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" PartnerClaimType="given_name" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" PartnerClaimType="family_name" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" PartnerClaimType="name" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="socialIdpAuthentication" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" PartnerClaimType="iss" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectIdExternalTenant" PartnerClaimType="sub" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="federatedGivenName" PartnerClaimType="given_name" DefaultValue="Not Set"/>            
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="federatedSurname" PartnerClaimType="family_name" DefaultValue="Not Set"/>      
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="federatedDisplayName" PartnerClaimType="name" DefaultValue="Not Set"/>     
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="federatedIDPEmailAddress" PartnerClaimType="email" DefaultValue="Not Set"/>     
      </OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaimsTransformations>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateRandomUPNUserName"/>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserPrincipalName"/>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateAlternativeSecurityId"/>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateSubjectClaimFromAlternativeSecurityId"/>
      </OutputClaimsTransformations>
      <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-SocialLogin"/>
      <EnabledForUserJourneys>OnItemExistenceInStringCollectionClaim</EnabledForUserJourneys>
    </TechnicalProfile>
```

Here's the setup for the app registration on the federation idp side.  Note the settings saying you can only enable openid and offline_access scopes.

See attached pictures
[fed1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lD2iU.png)
[fed2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qAua.png)

When we login through our home realm discover page, it takes us to the federated Idp, we login to that but we cannot get the email claim back, given_name, family_name, name, sub are all there but it doesn't populate the email claim.  Any ideas why this claim won't come through?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because the federated IdP is not returning a claim called “email”. Or your relying party output claims do not include an output claim for “email”, or both.

Comment: The metadata is irrelevant here. Your issue is simply claims mapping. If the IdP you want B2C to connect to is AAD, then email is only returned for users with o365 mailboxes setup. The app insights logs will show the token AAD returns to B2C, that will give you the answers as to if and how the email claim is retuned by AAD.

Comment: Thanks Jas,  this is the issue we have, the users don't have o365 mailboxes setup.  Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Then you can rely on a different claim. Eg preferred_username. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/id-tokens#claims-in-an-id-token

Comment: Thanks again Jas, we used a different claim in the end and then mapped it over to the email field in our destination IDP. It's only for our test environment so it's all good.

Comment: I have similar issue but in my case the email from federated AAD is saved as "Alternate email" instead of "Email" - any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "**email**", try "**signInNames.emailAddress**".

Search your **TrustFrameworkBase.xml** file for "**signInNames.emailAddress**" to confirm that it is there.

Here is a list of user attributes:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-profile-attributes

Comment: Thanks Ali, this is the email claim coming back from the IDP if we use the underlying AD instance, if we use the B2C RP then we never get the email back